# Stack List with Edit Button using Divs

Tags: css, layout, html

I am trying to build a Stack List using DIV's I have 3 divs displaying horizontally however I want one of these divs to be similar to an edit button that will allways appear top right regardless of the other divs.  Here is an example.

......................................
| xxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx | edit |
............................|        |
| xxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx |        |
......................................

So I can add multiple rows to the left but the edit button will always be top right.  I could develop this using tables but I am sure you DIV Experts have a better solution.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position absolute` for this:

for example

css:

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
}
.edit{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="edit"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Check this article http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I have used this but I didnt come to any avail?